# Creating a weak_ptr without having another smart pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

Let a class A and a class B. Each instance of class A owns from 0 to N instances of class B. When the instance of A is deleted, then instances of B are deleted too.

For example :

```
class parent
{
private:

    vector< unique_ptr< child > > m_children;

public:

    weak_ptr< child > create_child()
    {
        m_children.push_back( move( make_unique< child >( ??? ) ) );
        return m_children.back();
    }
};

class child
{
private:

    weak_ptr< parent > m_parent;

public:

    child( weak_ptr< parent > parent ) : m_parent( parent ) { }
};
```

One could, having a `shared_ptr< parent >` manually created a `child` using that pointer. But, within the scope of the class `parent`, all we have is `this`, not a `shared_ptr` to `this` because we have no idea of the `parent` instance is stored, and thus we can't create a `weak_ptr` out of this `shared_ptr` that we don't have.

So my question is : how can you check, within the `child` class scope, that the `parent` instance hasn't been released before using it ? How can I return a "safe" pointer when creating a `child` ? Thank you.

Comment: You can not get a `weak_ptr` from a `unique_ptr`, only from a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: You're probably looking for [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Comment: @Quentin That seems to be what I need, but according to what I read it requires the parent to be stored into a shared_ptr. The user of the class may forget to do so, even if it's mentionned in the documentation, because there's no strong protection against it, so it looks a bit unsafe to me, unless there is something I don't understand.

Comment: Why does `create_child` need to return a weak pointer? Why can't you return a normal pointer? You say you want a safe pointer, but why isn't a simple pointer safe in your case?

Comment: @KABoissonneault How do you know, within the context of the child class, if the parent pointed to by the "simple pointer" has been release or not ? That's one of the purposes of smart pointers.

Comment: @Virus721 C++17 mandades that `std::bad_weak_ptr` be thrown if `this` is not held by a `std::shared_pointer` when calling `shared_from_this`. In the meantime, the behaviour is formally undefined, But you usually get a crash IIRC.

Comment: @Virus721 You know from `parent`'s contract. The contract should say when `child` is released. At this point, the client should make sure the contract is never violated

Comment: Smart pointers are not a convenient way to delegate all responsibilities to the runtime: you should understand the problems you're trying to solve, and only when a problem can't be solved in a deterministic way (ex: lifetime over multiple threads is needed), then you need smart reference counting and `weak_ptr`

Comment: @KABoissonneault If something isn't coded properly, I don't want the whole program to violate memory and crash, but an exception to be thrown instead. Yes I do have to know what I'm doing, but in the real world people are going to do coding mistakes, even the most experienced people.

Comment: @Quentin Ho well I could make the constructors non-public and create a static method that will force new instances to be stored into shared_ptr instances.

Comment: @Virus721 that's a pretty good solution IMO.

Comment: Since `child` is stored as `unique_ptr` inside `parent`, it makes no sense to check *within the `child` class scope that `parent` was released*, since it would have already being destructed when `parent` is released. I'm assuming that you mean to check _automatically the existence of the `child` instance before using a pointer to it_ instead. If I'm correct, then you'll need a little more than just a factory for the parent that returns `shared_ptr`. Or was the `unique_ptr< child >` just an oversimplification of the real code for this question here?

Comment: @Virus721: "*I don't want the whole program to violate memory and crash, but an exception to be thrown instead.*" Why? Is there a way to reasonably recover from it? If not, what does it matter if you just reference NULL or throw an exception; the program crashes either way. And if you do have a way to recover... how do you do that?

Comment: @Virus721 "_If something isn't coded properly, I don't want the whole program to violate memory and crash_" Then you should consider programming in Java, or JS, or another "memory safe" programming language. *You cannot guarantee that in C or C++, period.*